# How To Add A Landing Page To A Meteor App?

Tags: templates, meteor, canvas, routes

**routes.js**

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home');
});
Router.route('wall', function () {
  this.render('Wall');
});
```

**landing.html**

```
<template name="home">
...
</template>
```

**drawingApp.html**

```
<body>
{{> wall}}
</body>

<template name="wall">
... 
{{> canvas}}
...    
</template>
<template name="canvas">
...
</template>
```

**drawingApp.js**

```
...
Template.wall.events({
...
```

If I include `<body> {{> wall}} </body>`, the landing page renders below the app. If I delete `<body> {{> wall}} </body>`, landing page renders properly, but when button is clicked to enter, it opens a non-functioning app. (Edited since first posted trying many things, but core issue remains the same). Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: are you using ```iron-router```? If so, get rid of the ```<head>``` and ```<body>``` tags. Iron router adds it's own head / body on routes. See if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm using iron:router. I pulled out the script tags in the head and added them in meteor packages, but home.html still renders below the app. If I get rid of <body> {{> wall}} </body>, my drawing app loses functionality.

Comment: For example, in .js `Template.wall.events({

  "click button.clear": function (event) {
    Meteor.call('clear', function() {
      canvas.clear();
    });
  },

  "click button.darkblue": function () {
    lastX=0;
    lastY=0;
    strokeColor = "darkblue";
    opacity = "1";
  },`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove calling wall template from body tags.

So your wall.html will be:

```
<head>
  <title>LKG Canvas</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="wall">

<!-- <h1>{{title}}</h1> -->
  <div id="settings">
    <div>
      <button class='eraser' button id="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></button>
      <button class='clear' button id="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
      ...
    </div>    

  <div id="settings">
    <button class='thinnest'>1</button>
    ...   
  </div>

  <div id="settings">
    <button class='shade'>3%</button>
  </div>

{{> canvas}}

</template>

<template name="canvas">
<div class="centerize">
    <div id="canvas" style="background-color: #333; width: 1250px; height: 550px;"></div>
    <br>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <div id="previewImage"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. When I remove <body>{{> wall}}
</body>

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that when I remove <body>{{> wall}} </body>, I loose all functionality in my app.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

**router.js**

```
Router.route ( '/', {
    name:'home',
    layoutTemplate:'index',
});

Router.route('/wall', {
  name:'wall',
   layoutTemplate:'index',
});
```

**home.html is as is, no changes:**

```
<template name="home">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Heading</h1> 
        <p>Some text here.</p> 
      </div>
      <div>
          <div class="centerize">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="wall" role="button">Draw</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**wall.html, removed the `<body>` stuff**

```
<template name="wall">

<!-- <h1>{{title}}</h1> -->
  <div id="settings">
    <div>
      <button class='eraser' button id="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></button>
      <button class='clear' button id="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
      ...
    </div>    

  <div id="settings">
    <button class='thinnest'>1</button>
    ...   
  </div>

  <div id="settings">
    <button class='shade'>3%</button>
  </div>

{{> canvas}}

</template>

<template name="canvas">
<div class="centerize">
    <div id="canvas" style="background-color: #333; width: 1250px; height: 550px;"></div>
    <br>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <div id="previewImage"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

**index.html**

```
<template name="index">
     {{> yield}}
</template>
```

Index.html basically encompasses the other routes that will render in the `yield` region.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts blueren. But, when I implemented the above, I lost functionality in my drawing app. Whenever I get rid of `<body> {{> wall}} </body>`, it disables the functionality in my app. Maybe I should try another way to get a landing page to load before the app? Maybe without using iron:router will work. I'm researching it, but haven't come up with any good ideas on my own yet. Thanks again for trying! It's very appreciated.